# Chrome extension (content scripts and match patterns) - only match digits in URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pattern-matching

I'm about to write my first Chrome Extension, but I'm just wondering if you can really only use "*" and "?" when declaring the "matches" pattern and the "include_globs" and "exclude_globs" patterns in manifest.json?

With regex, I'd declare this kind of pattern: "example.com/[0-9]+"

"example.com/*" however would match any kind of characters after "example.com/", but I want only digits to be matched.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), it seems that only `*` is a special character and that the patterns are not treated as regexes. (there are no mentions of regular expressions on that page actually)

I would suggest using `example.com/*` and wrap any action you want to take with a check on the URL where you'll be able to use any regex you want.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's what I ended up doing. Just re-checking the URL. I just wanted to be sure that there isn't another way. Thanks anyways :)!

Comment: One benefit of doing it that way is that, were you to change the URLs you want to match, you could do it and update your extension without having your users get a warning about you changing the permissions. (or worse: having your extension disabled with a notice to re-enable)